c++ changing the data within the object, it returns to the original state
I am trying to develop a trade simulation for practical purposes.
At the end of the code, I see that the values within the object have changed, but when it returns, it continues with the initial data. I couldn't understand where my mistake is. Thanks.
The logic is quite simple: give tokens to the seller and receive USDT in return, or vice versa.

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int getRandomNumber(int min, int max) {
    return min + rand() % ((max + 1) - min);
}

class Wallet {
private:
    double token;
    double usdt;

public:
    Wallet(double token, double usdt) : token(token), usdt(usdt) {}

    void deposit(const string& asset, double amount) {
        if (asset == "token") {
            token += amount;
        }
        else {
            usdt += amount;
        }
    }

    void withdraw(const string& asset, double amount) {
        if (asset == "token") {
            token -= amount;
        }
        else {
            usdt -= amount;
        }
    }

    double get(const string& asset) const {
        if (asset == "token") {
            return token;
        }
        else {
            return usdt;
        }
    }

    void print() const {
        cout << "Token Amount: " << token << " | Usdt Amount: " << usdt << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(nullptr)));

    Wallet main(150, 5000);
    Wallet w1(150, 50);
    Wallet w2(150, 50);
    Wallet w3(150, 50);
    Wallet w4(150, 50);
    Wallet w5(150, 50);
    Wallet pool(2500, 1000);

    vector<Wallet> wallets = { w1, w2, w3, w4, w5 };
    vector<Wallet> allWallets = { main, w1, w2, w3, w4, w5, pool };

    while (true) {
        // Current Pool Price
        double price = pool.get("usdt") / pool.get("token");
        cout << "Current Price: $" << price << endl;

        for (const auto& wal : allWallets) {
            wal.print();
        }
        Sleep(3000);

        // Select a random wallet
        int ind = getRandomNumber(0, wallets.size() - 1);
        Wallet& wal = wallets[ind];
        double usdt = wal.get("usdt");
        double token = wal.get("token");
        cout << "Selected Wallet Token Amount: " << token << endl;
        cout << "Selected Wallet Usdt Amount: " << usdt << endl;
        cout << endl;

        // Transaction Amount
        int side = getRandomNumber(0, 1);
        double amount = getRandomNumber(3, 6);

        // Buy
        if (side == 0) {
            if (usdt >= amount) {
                wal.withdraw("usdt", amount);
                pool.deposit("usdt", amount);

                double tokenAmount = amount / price;
                wal.deposit("token", tokenAmount);
                pool.withdraw("token", tokenAmount);
            }
            else {
                double transferAmount = main.get("usdt") / 5;
                wal.deposit("usdt", transferAmount);
                main.withdraw("usdt", transferAmount);
                continue;
            }
        }
        else { // Sell
            double tokenAmount = amount / price;
            if (token >= tokenAmount) {
                wal.withdraw("token", tokenAmount);
                pool.deposit("token", tokenAmount);

                double usdtAmount = tokenAmount * price;
                wal.deposit("usdt", usdtAmount);
                pool.withdraw("usdt", usdtAmount);
            }
            else {
                double transferAmount = main.get("token") / 5;
                wal.deposit("token", transferAmount);
                main.withdraw("token", transferAmount);
                continue;
            }
        }

        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}


At the end of the code -- Exactly which "code" are you referring to?  You have a class with member functions, and a main() function.  Second, I suggest not using random numbers for input and instead use known values that duplicate the error.  Once you have the program working with non-random numbers, then you can introduce random numbers.  Right now, every time you run the program, the target changes all due to using random numbers.  This makes the code harder to debug.

Also, vector<Wallet> allWallets = { main, w1, w2, w3, w4, w5, pool }; -- a vector stores copies, not references.  You are probably expecting that w1, w2, etc. in allWallets is the same as the w1, w2, etc. declared in main and in wallets.  They are not.

vector<Wallet> wallets = { w1, w2, w3, w4, w5 };
vector<Wallet> allWallets = { main, w1, w2, w3, w4, w5, pool };

This is your problem, you are constructing a set of Wallets on the stack and then copying them into the vectors. Because these are vectors of Wallets, not references to the original Wallet. Hence a copy is made for every one.
Then you update the Wallets in wallets, but print out the data from allWallets, which also contains copies of the originals.
you can fix it by either storing Wallet pointers (and then having to manage the originals so they do not get deleted whilst still in use) or using a smart pointer such as unique_ptr to handle this for you.
All objects in C++ are treated as types, like a big fat int, and thus have the same semantics as primitive types. You can create them on the stack or heap as a result, this is not the same as many other languages that treat objects as heap-only and give you a reference as the variable you work with, silently managing the link to the original. C++ is better, it gives you what you ask for.

In this case, maybe std::shared_ptr<Wallet> can be used as the smart pointer.
